# Test self-executing function wit Jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I understand reaching 100% unit test coverage shouldn't be a goal. I have actually excluded `index.js` from the coverage tests, I'm just interested to know how it would be done.

How can the self-executing function in `index.js` be tested? I'd like to test that it calls `scrape`.

`index.js`:

```js
import scrape from './scrape';

const main = (async () => {
  await scrape();
})();

export default main;
```

What I have tried:

```js
import main from './index';

const scrape = jest.fn();

describe('On the index file', () => {
  it('scrape executes automatically', async () => {
    await main();
    expect(scrape).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

This errors with `TypeError: (0 , _index.default) is not a function`

I see that `main` isn't a function but I haven't managed to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my test strategy, you can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/23.x/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) method mock the `scrape` module.

`index.ts`:

```js
import scrape from './scrape';

const main = (async () => {
  return await scrape();
})();

export default main;
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import scrape from './scrape';
import main from './';

jest.mock('./scrape.ts', () => jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('fake data'));

describe('main', () => {
  test('should return data', async () => {
    const actualValue = await main;
    expect(actualValue).toBe('fake data');
    expect(scrape).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58674975/index.spec.ts (7.434s)
  main
    ✓ should return data (5ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.684s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58674975